# Cannot make requests even when CORS is enabled?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, cors, same-origin-policy

I am trying to call an API built in Laravel at `http://localhost:8000` from an AngularJS application at `http://localhost`. I am getting an error saying:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/auth. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I sent an OPTIONS request at the `http://localhost:8000` via POSTMAN and this was the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *, chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Cache-Control → no-cache
Connection → close
Content-Type → text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date → Mon, 29 Dec 2014 06:33:26 GMT
Host → localhost:8000
Vary → Origin
X-Powered-By → PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
```

From what I can see, all methods are allowed from all origins. I don't understand why won't this work. What am I missing?

Comment: Which server and version are you using for deployment?

Comment: I am using the PHP server which is used for testing I guess. I just run `php artisan serve` and it fires up the application on `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Instead of trying to fix this temporary issue, serve the static pages from the rest server, or use a webserver to proxy the two connections into one host

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make some changes to $httpProvider as well

http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/